# Tensorflow 2.0 concrete function structured_input_signature return value

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I'm having some difficulty understanding the return types of `structured_input_signature` when inspecting a `tf.ConcreteFunction`.

In the google docs https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/concrete_function#using_a_concrete_function a tuple is returned. For example

```
@tf.function
def power(a,b):
  print('Tracing "power"\n')
  return a**b

float_power = power.get_concrete_function(
  a = tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32),
  b = tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.float32))

print(float_power.structured_input_signature)
print(float_power.structured_outputs)
```

prints

```
Tracing "power"

((TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='a'), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')), {})
Tensor("Identity:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

However, when the module is saved and loaded, the output of  is slightly different:

```
float_power_mod = tf.Module()
float_power_mod.float_power = float_power
tf.saved_model.save(float_power_mod, './float_power_mod')

mod_4 = tf.saved_model.load('./float_power_mod')
float_power_func = mod_4.signatures['serving_default']
print(float_power_func.structured_input_signature)
```

prints

```
((),
 {'a': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='a'),
  'b': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')})
```

What's the logic behind populating the tuple vs the dict in the return tuple of structured_input_signature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

`dict` allows us to pass keyworded arguments to a function, so that we can tag the real-valued input tensors to the corresponding placeholders accepted by TF.

```
result = float_power_func(a=tf.constant(2.), b=tf.constant(3.))
```

## Long answer

In order to save a TF model, first, we need to serialise tensors. Under the exported directory you can find a `.pb` file, that is the protobuf used to serialise your entire model. By model, I mean a collection of tensors and the relationships of these tensors, all of them are captured in protobuf. While TF has provided functions for serialisation and taking your code for example

```
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import nested_structure_coder

coder = nested_structure_coder.StructureCoder()
signature_proto = coder.encode_structure(float_power.structured_input_signature)
print(signature_proto)
```

prints

```
tuple_value {
  values {
    tuple_value {
      values {
        tensor_spec_value {
          name: "a"
          shape {
          }
          dtype: DT_FLOAT
        }
      }
      values {
        tensor_spec_value {
          name: "b"
          shape {
          }
          dtype: DT_FLOAT
        }
      }
    }
  }
  values {
    dict_value {
    }
  }
}
```

However, the above serialised structure does not satisfy the needs. We cannot assign an input to a key because the return is a tuple.

```
((TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='a'), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')), {})
```

As you may realised, the real process of serialising a model is much more complicated, which involves adding new tags and signatures for serving, in-replica and cross-replia context for distribute strategy, among so many other. Regradless of all the complexity, the core is the same, get signatures and serialise them, the code is sourced [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/saved_model/save.py#L888)

```
signatures = signature_serialization.canonicalize_signatures(signatures)
```

The `signatures` get repacked and the input tensors are moved inside of `dict_value` as key-value pairs

```
value {
    canonicalized_input_signature {
      tuple_value {
        values {
          tuple_value {
          }
        }
        values {
          dict_value {
            fields {
              key: "a"
              value {
                tensor_spec_value {
                  name: "a"
                  shape {
                  }
                  dtype: DT_FLOAT
                }
              }
            }
            fields {
              key: "b"
              value {
                tensor_spec_value {
                  name: "b"
                  shape {
                  }
                  dtype: DT_FLOAT
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and decoding it you will get

```
((),
 {'a': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='a'),
  'b': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.float32, name='b')})
```